# Surrogate Chinese Characters Not Displaying iText Java

Tags: java, unicode, itext

Using iText 5.5.11 from the maven repo https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf/5.5.11

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException {

        final String text = "BMP: \u6d4b \u8bd5  Surrogate: \uD841\uDF0E \uD841\uDF31 \uD859\uDC02";

        BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arialuni.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font font = new Font(baseFont, 6.8f);

        Document doc = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("out.pdf"));
        doc.open();

        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();

        p.add(new Phrase(text, font));

        doc.add(p);

        doc.close();
    }
}
```

The non-surrogate characters in the basic multilingual plane are rendered on the resulting pdf, but the surrogate characters are not.

**Edit:** Also tried with font "STSong-Light" with encoding "UniGB-UCS2-H" (as in examples in book). Same result - surrogate characters missing.

**Edit2:** Got it to work with "SimSun-ExtB" font

Comment: 1) What size is your arialuni.ttf - kilobytes or megabytes?  It should be megabytes.  2) Has Chinese (East Asian fonts) been installed on your machine?

Comment: @cup 22MB - I use Arial in this example because the glyphs display correctly in Notepad with Arial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually a sign that the font being used (in this case Arial) does not have the glyphs for your characters.

Comment: You can see that Arial has the glyphs by pasting  (\uD841\uDF0E) into notepad and changing the font to Arial